# Why am I getting Segmentation fault for using array of char pointers?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to play around with c and pointers since I'm new to the language but I'm not sure why I'm getting a segmentation fault, when I have initialized everything to null then going to re-write the array of char pointers? Can someone explain what I did wrong?

```
#define MAX_SIZE 70    
void gridTest(char*[]);

int main()
{
    char *grid[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
    testGrid(grid);
    return 0;
}    

void testGrid(char *grid[]){
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
        *grid[i] = ' ';
    }
    for(int j=0;j<MAX_SIZE;j++){          
        printf("The Character is space, test: %c",*grid[j],j);
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: You are not allocating memory for each pointer inside the array.

Comment: You have an array of ***null*** pointers. Then you do `*grid[i] = ' '` which dereference those null pointers, leading to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: And if you're just need space for a single `char` anyway, why an array of pointers to `char`? Why not a plain array of `char`?

Comment: `main()` initialises all the elements of `grid` to be null pointers.   `testGrid()` modifies data pointed to by those elements.   Doing that on null pointers is undefined behaviour.   `*grid[i] = ' ' ` does not magically convert `grid[i]` from a null pointer to something that can be written to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring an array of char pointers, you become responsible for making those pointers point to something.  If you just want to get a 70x70 grid, you can get around that by declaring `grid` as an array of char arrays:

```
char grid[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
```

That way, the memory is automatically allocated and ready for use.

`*grid[i]` is equivalent to `grid[i][0]`, so `testGrid` currently accesses only the first column in each row.  To access all cells in the grid, you could use two nested `for` loops and access them with `grid[i][j]` or similar.

Comment: then, If i don't want to use a pointer, how is it possible to return the char array that I passed?

Comment: The array acts as a pointer in many ways. In particular, you can pass the array as a pointer to a function, as you did with `testGrid`, and that function can still operate on the pointer as if it were an array. The difference is that with a pointer, you can change what it points to, while an array always "points" to its data.

Comment: Oooooooooooooooooh Wow, I never knew this. that solves my issue then. I just tested it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Check this line

```
  *grid[i] = ' ';
```

you are trying to store the *space* character in a memory pointed to by `grid[i]`, that's cool, but where does that one point to?

Answer is: Invalid memory (a null pointer, it is). The memory address you're trying to use is invalid and attempt to deference it invokes undefined behavior.

That being said, seeing your usage, you don't need an array of `char` pointers, an array of `char` would suffice. Change your array definition to

```
 char grid[MAX_SIZE] = {0};
```

and change the called function as

```
void testGrid(char grid[]){

        for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
              grid[i] = ' ';
         }
        for(int j=0;j<MAX_SIZE;j++){
           printf("The Character is space, test: %c",grid[j],j);
        }
 }
```

Comment: but now in this case, I'm not actually passing the array, I'm making a copy of it, thats why I was trying to use pointer, so I can pass it by reference

Comment: @decentProgrammer why?

Comment: so that when I later modify the program to make a simple text game, I won't have to deal with a "copy" of the data and not the actual data.

Comment: @decentProgrammer Don't forget that arrays naturally decays to *pointers* to their first element. When you have an argument like `char grid[]` it's really the same as `char *grid`. I.e. all that is passed is the *pointer*, not the whole array.